# Split the first item of a python list using whitespace

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, whitespace

I have a simple list as below:

```
lst = ['11 12221/n']
```

I want to split the first item into a list as below:

```
['11', '12221']
```

This seems relatively simple to me but I cant get it to work. My first approach was to do:

```
lst[0].split()
```

but when I print list no changes have occurred. I therefore tried:

```
newLst=[]

for x in lst:
    newList.append(x.split())
```

But from this I get

```
[['11', '12221\n']]
```

I think I must fundamentally be misunderstanding list comprehension, could someone explain why my code didnt work and how it should be done?

Thank you

Comment: It seems that you need to use "extend" instead of "append". See [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
lst = ['11 12221\n']

lst = lst[0].split()
```

`list[0]` gets you `'11 12221\n'` which you then `split()` and assign back to `lst` giving you:

```
['11', '12221\n']
```

You have to assign the split back to the variable

Note: You should not name your variables as ony of the python reserved words. Use perhaps `lst` instead.

If you only want to split at a `space`, do: `split(' ')` instead.

Demo: http://repl.it/R8w

Comment: `lst[0].split()` will *remove* the trailing `\n` newline, so the output will be `['11', '12221']`.

Comment: @PaulBarr This code doesn't do what you claim to want. If this answer fixes your problem you should edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: @juanchopanza what result would my question want literally? I have probably misused the term whitespace

Comment: @PaulBarr You claim you want this: `['11', '12221\n']`. The code above gives `['11', '12221']`.

Comment: @juanchopanza ok, I meant to split ['11 12221\n'] into ['11', '12221'], what would the correct terminology be for this?

Comment: @PaulBarr Just fix your answer so that it asks for what you actually want.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
>>> lst = ['11 12221\n']
>>> # Split on spaces explicitly so that the \n is preserved
>>> lst[0].split(" ")
['11', '12221\n']
>>> # Reassign lst to the list returned by lst[0].split(" ")
>>> lst = lst[0].split(" ")
>>> lst
['11', '12221\n']
>>>
```

Comment: I think it originally was lst anyway…

Comment: @thecoder16 - No, the OP changed it.  It used to be `list`.  Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Okay.  I can’t see a “edited x secs ago” link though…

Comment: @thecoder16 - He edited his question within the 5-minute grace period given after posting.  Thus, the changes to the post will not be recorded in the edit history.

Comment: @thecoder16, iCodez is right. It __did__ used to be `list` in the OP's question.

Comment: @sshashank124 Okay, I am just asking!

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[part for entry in origlist for part in entry.split(None, 1)]
```

This allows for multiple strings and splits just once (so only two elements are ever created for each string).

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result of the call to `std.split` to something:

```
>>> my_list = ['11 12221\n']     # do not name a variable after a std lib type
>>> my_list = my_list[0].split()
>>> print my_list
['11', '12221']
```

The main issue is that the call to `str.split` returns a list of strings. You were just discarding the result.